# How do I merge the temp file and file name together after the file has been uploaded?

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP to collect documents from users. I have a simple HTML form that allows users to upload documents. Once the document has been uploaded, I send myself an e-mail containing the document the user uploaded as an attached file.

My problem is, when I use `$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"]`, the file is sent but it is in the wrong format and does not preserve the original file name. When I try sending the file with `$_FILES["resume"]["name"]`, the document isn’t sent.

How do I send an e-mail containing the file immediately it is uploaded, in the right format and with the right name?

Update, here is my current code (I am using Mailgun to send the email):

```
`    $mgClient = new Mailgun('key-xxxxx');
        $domain = "mg.xxxxx.com";
        $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
          'from'    => $postdata['fullname'].' <'.$postdata['email'].'>',
          'to'      => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
          'subject' => $postdata['fullname'].' has sent you a resumé',
          'text'    => 'This is a resumé from '.$postdata['fullname'].' 
        applying to be part of the xxxx team. His/her resumé is attached to 
        this email.'
        ), array(
        'attachment' => array(''.$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"].'')`
```

Comment: You need to read the file from `$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"]` but you can use `$_FILES["resume"]["name"]` as the name for the attachment. Hard to say exactly how without seeing the code you use for sending the email.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, I have updated the question with a section of my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the official [`mailgun-php SDK`](https://packagist.org/packages/mailgun/mailgun-php), you can set the file's name into the `attachment` array:

```
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-xxxxx');
$domain = "mg.xxxxx.com";
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(/* ... */), array(
    'attachment' => array(
        // array entry for each file:
        array(
            // filePath: path to the actual file
            'filePath' => $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"],

            // remoteName: user-visible attachment name
            'remoteName' => $_FILES["resume"]["name"]
        )
    )
));
```